# Open URL in Browser and Change Apps View - Android Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

How can I open a URL in the device's default browser and also change the view of the app so after they are done looking at the opened URL and they go back to the app, they are in a new view?

Below is what I have so far:

```
            Button btnOkay = FindViewById<Button>(Application.Context.Resources.GetIdentifier("btnOkay", "id", Application.Context.PackageName));
            btnOkay.Click += (sender, eventArgs) =>
            {
                // Open Survey Monkey Survey in Browser
                var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("https://www.example.com/");
                var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, uri);
                StartActivity(intent);

                // Go to Thank you view in app.
                intent = new Intent(this, typeof(PatientPostVisitSurveyThanksActivity));
                StartActivity(intent);

            };
```

The issue with this is, it goes to the next view, and will only open the URL in the browser if I click back to go to the original view.

Comment: There is no auto return to your app when launching any 3rd-party app unless they have provided direct support for that (And apps like Chrome do not). I would recommend using a Chrome Custom Tab on top of your app so when the user closes the browser tab or navigates "back" they are returned to your app

Comment: Note about the [tag:visual-studio] tag: if you read the description, it says *"Use this tag if you have a specific question about Visual Studio features and functionality. DO NOT use this tag on questions regarding code which merely happened to be written in Visual Studio."*

Comment: @SushiHangover, I understand this and I don't want the app to automatically come back after the webpage is viewed. I just want the app view to be changed when the user manually goes back into the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I just want the app view to be changed when the user manually goes back into the app.

You can use the Activity lifecycles for this. Your app's last Activity will execute `OnResume` after the user press back (or selects it from the active app list). Set a flag before launching the browser and test for that flag in the `OnResume`

```
btnOkay.Click += (sender, eventArgs) =>
{
    GotoNewActivity = true;

    // Open Survey Monkey Survey in Browser
    var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("https://www.example.com/");
    var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, uri);
    StartActivity(intent);
};

bool GotoNewActivity;
protected override void OnResume()
{
    base.OnResume();
    if (GotoNewActivity)
    {
        GotoNewActivity = false;
        // Go to Thank you view in app.
        var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(ThankYouActivity));
        StartActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for.